# ¿Como pasar datos de un JTable de un frame a un JCombobox de otro frame?(resultado no esperado)

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-8.2, interfaz-gráfica

Buen Dia Amigos.

Resulta que quiero dar click a un tabla de un frame y este dato se me capture para enviarlo a un Combobox de otro frame.

lo pasos que hago se encuentran en la siguiente imagen, lo puse en una imagen para que vean que es lo normal y deberia funcionar, pero simplemente el resultado no es el esperado.

[image]

he probado de distintas maneras, colocando los componentes publicos, instanciando los frames para poder manejar el combox desde el otro frame, tratando de enviar datos desde mi segundo frame al primero, tantas cosas, que se agotaron las ideas.
y les coloque esta ya que es la que me parece que deberia duncionar mejor, pero el resultado es absurdo.

aqui esta el codigo legible:
frame donde esta el combo box:

```
    private void buscar_catebtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
            buscar_categoria bcate=new buscar_categoria();
            bcate.setVisible(true);              
}


 public void getDato(String nombrecat){
        categoria_prodventacombo.setSelectedItem(nombrecat);
    }
```

frame donde se encuentra la tabla:

```
    private void categoria_tablaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
            int filaseleccionada= categoria_tabla.getSelectedRow();
            if (filaseleccionada==-1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha seleccionado ninguna fila");
            }else{
                String nombre=String.valueOf(modelo_categorias.getValueAt(categoria_tabla.getSelectedRow(),1));
                System.out.print(nombre);
                prodventa.getDato(nombre);
            }                
}
```

Comment: tu JComoBox es editable? Lo puedes verificar con el método isEditable(), si no lo es, hay que hacerla editable. Por otro lado, como estás supongo manejando Strings (cadenas), necesitas verificar que tanto las del modelo como las del checkbox esten con idénticas, esto es mayúsculas/minúsculas y trimeadas, con el método trim(). Ya que si no están idénticas no las va a seleccionar.

Comment: Gracias, por yu respuesta, ya lo consegui, coloque el combobox public static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo solucione asi, en el frame donde esta el combobox:
hay que colocar el combobox public static
(click derecho en el combobox-> selecionar Customize Code-> seleccionar public y chekear static)

segundo: hacer un metodo en ese frame public static tambien

```
public static void getDato(){
        String nombre=frame.variablestatica;   
        combobox.setSelectedItem(nombre);
    }
```

en el otro frame instancie una variable estatica, la que me guardara el dato, cuando haga click en la tabla

```
static String variableestatica="";
```

y cuando se haga mouse click en la tabla
llamo al metodo estatico, sin instanciar:

```
variableestatica=String.valueOf(modelo_tabla.getValueAt(tabla.getSelectedRow(),1));
            getDato();
```